Access uri from another context
I'm trying to send my selected uri to another app(via Intent putExtra),but,for some reason,I can access the uri documents tree only in the original app(the app that launched the file picker dialog),and not on the "receiver" app.
This is the first app code:
private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        try {
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a Directory"),
                    FILE_SELECT_CODE);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.tiferet.update", "com.tiferet.update.MainActivity"));
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

And this is the second app(which receives the intent)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        HandleBundle();
    }

  private void HandleBundle() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri uri=getIntent().getData();
            // Check if the bundle is not null
            if (uri != null) {
                    ProcessMe(uri);
            } else {
                // Handle the case where the bundle is null
                Log.d("itapimu", "uri is null.");
            }
    }

public void ProcessMe(Uri uri) {
        Uri childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(
                uri,
                DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri)
        );
        // get document file from children uri
        DocumentFile tree = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, childrenUri);
        // get the list of the documents
        DocumentFile[] documents = tree.listFiles();
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(documents.length), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// is 0!!

        if (documents != null) {
            for (DocumentFile doc : documents) { //doesn't event enter that loop
                Log.w("itapiIkosher" , doc.getName());
            }
        }
    }

Now I validate that the received Uri is valid,and it's path is good,and everything...but still,I'm unable to access the folder documents...
the documents  length is 0,and it doesn't even enter the for loop..(When I implement theProcessMe method on the first app,it works as charm...)

Having multiple apps rarely is the correct answer, for you or the user.
That said, you need to forward along permissions:
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.tiferet.update", "com.tiferet.update.MainActivity"));
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    startActivity(intent);

See this blog post of mine for more.
Conversely, you can remove that same line (intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);) from showFileChooser().

added that flag,still the same result. of course in they both apps manifests I have read&write&manage files permissions. @CommonsWare

I've tried even on lower android version...like android 9...and still there's no access to the document tree.....
